# Genetic algorithm for "smart dots" in python doesn't work

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, pygame, genetic-algorithm

For the past few days I've been trying to implement the so called "Smart dots" game. I first saw it on Code Bullet youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOZfhUcNiqk. Unfortunately it was coded in Processing language, while the only language I barely know is Python. I finished my python version of the game but some bugs have appeared.

The problem is that on the second generation dots that are selected to be the best just stop moving almost instantly. I think that it has something to do with me being bad at OOP and copying the Brain class wrong. Steps(which i use for movement) Jump from zero(that is set at the beginning) to max value(200) at the first or second looping of the main loop. But the problems don't stop there. At the next generation, when i try to set brain step to zero, it just breaks with:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'brain'
```

I tried setting up the new brain manually but i still get the same errors. If anyone who already made this or has time to spare can help me with this error or even project i would appreciate it.

I know the code has a lot of unused things but that's just the product of me trying to fix it
:(

The commented out code is some of the old code i used.

main2.py(main loop):

```
import pygame
import klase2

pygame.init()


def main():
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((klase2.WIN_W, klase2.WIN_H))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    population = klase2.Population()
    dots = population.return_dots(1000)
    goal = klase2.Goal()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        win.fill((255, 255, 255))

        goal.draw_goal(win)

        for dot in dots:
            dot.draw_dot(win)
            dot.update_dot()

        if population.all_dots_dead():
            # natural selection
            population.natural_selection()

            # mutation
            dots = population.mutate_dots()
            population.gen += 1
            print(population.gen)

        pygame.display.update()


main()
```

kase2(handles all the functions and classes):

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
from pygame import gfxdraw
import math
import random

pygame.init()

WIN_W = 500
WIN_H = 500


class Brain:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.step = 0
        self.size = size
        self.directionsx = np.array(np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=int(self.size / 2)))
        self.directionsy = np.array(np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=int(self.size / 2)))

    def clone(self):
        self.size = self.size
        self.directionsx = self.directionsx
        self.directionsy = self.directionsy
        self.step = 0


class Goal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = WIN_W / 2
        self.y = 10
        self.color = (255, 20, 20)
        self.r = 5

    def draw_goal(self, win):
        pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(win, int(self.x), int(self.y), self.r, self.color)
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(win, int(self.x), int(self.y), self.r, self.color)


class Dot:
    goal = Goal()

    def __init__(self):
        self.tick = 0
        self.goal = Goal()
        self.brain = Brain(400)
        self.velx = 0
        self.vely = 0
        self.accx = 0
        self.accy = 0
        self.x = WIN_W / 2
        self.y = WIN_H - 10
        self.r = 3
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)
        self.alive = True
        self.velLimit = 5
        self.fitness = 0

    def draw_dot(self, win):
        pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(win, int(self.x), int(self.y), self.r, self.color)
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(win, int(self.x), int(self.y), self.r, self.color)

    def move_dot(self):
        if self.brain.size / 2 > self.brain.step:
            self.accx = self.brain.directionsx[self.brain.step]
            self.accy = self.brain.directionsy[self.brain.step]
            self.brain.step += 1
        else:
            self.alive = False

        self.velx += self.accx
        self.vely += self.accy

        if self.velx > self.velLimit:
            self.velx = self.velLimit
        elif self.velx < -self.velLimit:
            self.velx = -self.velLimit

        if self.vely > self.velLimit:
            self.vely = self.velLimit
        elif self.vely < -self.velLimit:
            self.vely = -self.velLimit

        self.x += self.velx
        self.y += self.vely

    def update_dot(self):
        if not self.reached_goal():
            self.tick += 1
        if self.alive:
            self.move_dot()
            if self.x < 0 + self.r or self.x > WIN_W - self.r or self.y < 0 + self.r or self.y > WIN_H - self.r or self.reached_goal():
                self.alive = False

    def distance_to_goal(self):
        a = abs(self.x - self.goal.x)
        b = abs(self.y - self.goal.y)
        return math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)

    def reached_goal(self):
        if self.distance_to_goal() <= self.r + self.goal.r:
            return True
        return False

    def fitness_dot(self):
        if self.reached_goal():
            self.fitness = 1 / (self.brain.step)
        else:
            self.fitness = 1 / (self.distance_to_goal()**2)

        return self.fitness


class Population:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dots = []
        self.newDots = []
        self.gen = 0
        self.mutateChance = 800
        self.size = 0
        self.fitness_sum = 0

    def return_dots(self, size):
        self.size = size
        for _ in range(size):
            self.dots.append(Dot())
        return self.dots

    def all_dots_dead(self):
        for i in range(len(self.dots)):
            if self.dots[i].alive:
                return False
        return True

    def sort_dots(self):
        self.dots = sorted(self.dots, key=lambda dot: dot.fitness, reverse=True)

    def sum_fitness(self):
        for dot in self.dots:
            self.fitness_sum += dot.fitness_dot()
        return self.fitness_sum

    def get_parent(self):
        rand = random.uniform(0, self.fitness_sum)
        running_sum = 0
        for dot in self.dots:
            running_sum += dot.fitness
            if running_sum >= rand:
                return dot

    def natural_selection(self):
        for dot in self.dots:
            dot.fitness_dot()
        self.sort_dots()
        self.newDots.append(self.dots[0])
        self.sum_fitness()
        for i in range(1, len(self.dots)):
            parent = self.get_parent()
            self.newDots.append(Dot())
            self.newDots[i].brain = parent.brain
            self.newDots[i].brain.step = 0
        self.dots = self.newDots

    def mutate_dots(self):
        for i in range(1, len(self.dots)):
            rand = random.randint(0, 1000)
            if rand > self.mutateChance:
                self.dots[i].brain.directionsx = np.array(np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=int(self.dots[i].brain.size / 2)))
                self.dots[i].brain.directionsy = np.array(np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=int(self.dots[i].brain.size / 2)))
        return self.dots

    # def natural_selection(self):
    #     self.selectedDots = []
    #     for dot in self.dots:
    #         dot.fitness_dot()
    #     self.sort_dots()
    #     for i in range(0, int(len(self.dots) / 3)):
    #         self.selectedDots.append(self.dots[i])
    #         self.selectedDots[i].tick = 0
    #         self.selectedDots[i].velx = 0
    #         self.selectedDots[i].vely = 0
    #         self.selectedDots[i].accx = 0
    #         self.selectedDots[i].accy = 0
    #         self.selectedDots[i].x = WIN_W / 2
    #         self.selectedDots[i].y = WIN_H - 10
    #         self.selectedDots[i].alive = True
    #         self.selectedDots[i].fitness = 0
    #         self.selectedDots[i].brain.step = 0
    #         self.selectedDots[i].goal = Goal()
    #
    # def new_dots(self):
    #     for i in range(len(self.selectedDots), len(self.dots)):
    #         self.selectedDots.append(Dot())
    #     self.dots = self.selectedDots
    #
    # def mutate_dots(self):
    #     for i, dot in enumerate(self.dots):
    #         isMutating = random.randint(0, 1000)
    #         if self.mutateChance > isMutating and i > int(len(self.dots) / 3) and i < (2 * int((len(self.dots) / 3))):
    #             for j in range(len(dot.brain.directionsx)):
    #                 isMutatingDir = random.randint(0, 1000)
    #                 if isMutatingDir >= 800:
    #                     dot.brain.directionsx[j] = np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=1)
    #             for j in range(len(dot.brain.directionsy)):
    #                 isMutatingDir = random.randint(0, 1000)
    #                 if isMutatingDir >= 800:
    #                     dot.brain.directionsy[j] = np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=1)
    #     return self.dots
    '''

    def natural_selection(self):
        self.selectedDots = []
        for dot in self.dots:
            dot.fitness_dot()
        self.sort_dots()
        self.selectedDots = self.dots[0:int(0.3 * len(self.dots))]

    def new_dots(self):
        for i in range(len(self.dots) - int(0.3 * len(self.dots))):
            self.selectedDots.append(self.dots[i])
        self.dots = []

    def mutate_dots(self):
        for i, selectedDot in enumerate(self.selectedDots):
            self.tick = 0
            self.x = WIN_W / 2
            self.y = WIN_H - 10
            self.r = 3
            self.alive = True
            self.velLimit = 5
            self.fitness = 0

        self.dots = self.selectedDots
        return self.dots
    '''

    '''
    def mutate_dots(self):
        for i, selectedDot in enumerate(self.selectedDots):
            selectedDot.alive = True
            if i >= 1:
                isMutating = random.randint(0, 1000)
                if isMutating <= self.mutateChance:
                    for j in range(len(selectedDot.brain.directionsx)):
                        isMutatingDir = random.randint(0, 1000)
                        if isMutatingDir >= 800:
                            selectedDot.brain.directionsx[j] = np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=1)
                    for j in range(len(selectedDot.brain.directionsy)):
                        isMutatingDir = random.randint(0, 1000)
                        if isMutatingDir >= 800:
                            selectedDot.brain.directionsy[j] = np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=1)
                elif isMutating <= 800:
                    selectedDot.brain.directionsx = np.array(np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=200))
                    selectedDot.brain.directionsy = np.array(np.random.uniform(low=-2.5, high=2.5, size=200))
            self.newDots.append(selectedDot)

        return self.newDots
    '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NoneType error is caused by the get_parent method. It searches for a child dot, but has no return value if the search fails (same effect as *return None*). This code will get past that error

```
def get_parent(self):
    rand = random.uniform(0, self.fitness_sum)
    running_sum = 0
    for dot in self.dots:
        running_sum += dot.fitness
        if running_sum >= rand:
            return dot
    return self.dots[0]  # search failed, return 1st dot
```